# Adding a c++ executable icon to premake5 build script

Tags: c++, visual-c++, icons, premake

can someone confirm **if** and **how** can I add an C++ aplication icon in a premake5.lua script? The [icon](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/icon) property seems to work just for C#. I got an *.ico* format icon prepared, I just can't find a way how to set it in the premake script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend the @androidu answer for Windows:

```lua
filter { 'system:windows' }
  files { 'resources.rc', '**.ico' }
  vpaths { ['Resources/*'] = { '*.rc', '**.ico' }
filter {}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. So for windows it seems I just needed to include my `resources.rc` file to the compilation.

Contents of resources.rc:
`id ICON "../res/icon.ico"`

Will be back later with updates for osx and linux.